# Jenkins on Docker cannot connect to local repo

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I following this tutorial https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/#fork-sample-repository to create a Jenkins Pipeline.

My config for Pipeline section is

- Definition: Pipeline scrip from SCM
- SCM: git
  => Repository URL: I put my local path to my local repository according to the tutorial link mentioned above.

But I always get this error "**Failed to connect to repository : Command "git ls-remote -h -- file:///home/aaa/Projects/doit-webservice HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: fatal: '/home/aaa/Projects/doit-webservice' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.**"

I am sure I entered correct git credential for that repo.

My guess is, I am using Jenkins on Docker and the path to access that local folder is incorrect.

I tested another laptop which running Jenkins without Docker and it working fine.

Comment: You need to bind the folder containing your repository on your host to your container. See  https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the network drive to the server, and then use `docker volume` to host the network drive on the container, you can run the docker volume as the same user and group id also, so the permissions would work seamlessly, with no permissions errors when accessing the files from the host machine, or the Git server later on.

More information in the docker documentation,
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error. When creating my Jenkins container `"--volume "$HOME":/home \"` was missing. I was able to continue the tutorial successfully after stopping my Jenkins container and restarting with that line added.

Full script:

```
docker run --name jenkins-blueocean --rm --detach \
  --network jenkins --env DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker:2376 \
  --env DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/certs/client --env DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1 \
  --publish 8080:8080 --publish 50000:50000 \
  --volume jenkins-data:/var/jenkins_home \
  --volume jenkins-docker-certs:/certs/client:ro \
  --volume "$HOME":/home \
  myjenkins-blueocean:2.332.1-1
```